# How to mark Eclipse editor as dirty while not ignoring other changes made in the editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I added an OutlinePage to my Eclipse TextEditor and when changes are made in this Outline, the TextEditor has to be marked as dirty.
The proposed way to do this is to use

```
firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY)
```

However, I have to manage the dirty flag by myself as well and return it in

```
isDirty()
```

But that means, that the dirty flag is not automatically set if the TextEditor's content is changed. I thought about adding an IPartProperyChangeListener and changing the flag by myself. Is that the best way to to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use `ISaveablesSource` which allows your editor to have multiple `Saveable` objects. Each Saveable has a separate dirty flag.

If you are using a text editor based on `AbstractTextEditor` or one of its subclasses then the editor already implements `ISaveablesSource` and provides a `Saveable` for the main editor, so you would just add a `Saveable` for your outline data.

Comment: Do you know of any good documentation about how to use these Saveables?

Comment: Not really. The JavaDoc and source for ISaveablesSource and Saveable have some documentation. Some Eclipse editors use this, notably the Compare editor.

Comment: When my Saveable becomes 'dirty', the save button appears. However, when I click it, nothing happens, `Saveable.doSave` is not invoked. However, when I change something in the editor and save it, `Saveable.doSave` is also called.

Comment: What save button is that?

Comment: The Eclipse save button in the menu bar at the top. I think its better if I move this to a new question, so I can post some of my code.